# Multiple Server Deployment in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, deployment

I have a problem. I want to deployment more server. I doing only by only in visual studio on server and use folder publish. Has it solution for multiple deployment server in visual studio?

Comment: I use BitBucket Pipelines to build my project into a Docker container when I push to a specific branch. As part of the Pipelines script, that Docker container is pushed to Google Container Registry, and then the Google Kubernetes Engine deployment is updated with the latest image tag using Helm. I'm sure none of this is relevant to your situation, but you've not provided any real information about what your setup is like, so I'm telling you what one setup is like. Please edit your question if you want a targeted answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right. Before I edit my answer I don't use docker, kubernetes and other utilities. I just use the folder publishing process. Is that enough detail?

Comment: Not really. What is stopping you publishing to each server in turn?

Comment: Actually, I don't have a problem. I just want to make my job easier.

Comment: So is your question actually "how can I automate/streamline publishing (folder publish) my application to multiple servers?" ?

Comment: Like your question, I can find the answer when I search.  Thank you!